# Use NodeJS data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, swig-template

I have the follow route:

### Server

```
app.get('/claim/:id', compact.js(['global']), indexController.claim);
module.exports.claim=function(req,res){
    res.render('claim-note', { title: 'claim', noteId:req.params["id"]});
};
```

Now, I want to use the noteId variable inside my angular controller. Like:

### Client

```
controller("NoteController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
   $scope.noteId = {{noteId}};
}
```

How can I do that? The idea is that users use the direct link like claim/866317 so, it is already know when the page is open.

Comment: Where's the rest of your angular code? The http request, the controller... etc.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use following way to resolve this problem:

```
controller("NoteController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope,
$http){
   $scope.setNoteId = function(noteId) {
      $scope.noteId = noteId;
   }
}
```

In html:

```
<body ng-controller="NoteController" ng-init="setNoteId({{noteId}})">
...
</body>
```

Comment: The OP asked about getting the variable from `node.js` to angular. not how to set the variable on angular and use it only there

Comment: Yes. I have already answered this question. If you use this method, you can set the angular's variable with getting the variable from node.js by using ng-init directive. I assume that the {{noteId}} variable is coming from node.js.

Comment: So you assumed a part of the actual question. Which means, imo, you didn't answer the question.

Comment: In your solution, you use `ng-init` in the same place the `ng-controller` is set. which means that it's the same as just doing something in the actual controller when it is defined. Do you assume the `noteId` is set on a controller that is the `parent` of this controller? based on the fact you didn't add `nameCtrl` before it, it's on the `$scope`. If that's true, you can just use `$scope.noteId` in your controller and that variable will be available. You are trying to set `noteId` on the `$scope`, using a `noteId` from the `$scope`

Comment: In the NVO's question is about the NodeJS Swig template engine(In consolidate npm module). And swig template engine uses same curly braces {{}} with angular. So, {{noteId}} variable comes from the NodeJS. My simple solution sets angular $scope.noteId variable with getting the variable from NodeJS. I make an example for this question. You can check this link: https://github.com/endrcn/Use-NodeJS-data-in-Angular

Comment: oh cool. I guess I'm wrong. So, great answer man! thanks for the further explanation as well. I definitely learned something 

Comment: but how did you know the OP asked about the swig template engine?

Comment: The res.render() method is in the swig template engine. :))

Answer (score 0):

Solved via a hidden div in my html

```
<div id="noteId" class="hidden">#{noteId}></div>
```

and in my angular controller

```
$scope.id = $('#noteId').text;
```

Comment: use Angular's JQuery Lite inside angular code, for example `angular.element('#nodeId').text()`